# NullPointer when getting sharedPreferences in Application class

Tags: android

```
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
private SharedPreferences settings;
settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
```

When I use this code in a class that Extends Application I get a nullpointer on line 3 while it works when I do the same in an activity. Why is this?

I'm trying to create a singleton class for holding a few variables. Only 10 variables so not enough to use sqllite or so.

edit:
In my first call I get a DataClass singleton instance:

```
   boolean active = DataClass.getInstance().getBoolean("active");
```

complete DataClass:

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.util.Log;


public class DataClass extends Application  {
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

    private static DataClass instance = null;
    public static DataClass getInstance() {
          if(instance == null) {
             instance = new DataClass();
          }
          return instance;
       }


    private SharedPreferences settings;

    public DataClass()  {
        settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);  //nullpointer here
        Log.e("temp", "DataClass constructor executed");
    }


    public void setBoolean(boolean trueorfalse, String id)      {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(id, trueorfalse);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public boolean getBoolean(String id)        {
        return settings.getBoolean(id, false);
    }

}
```

edit: added stacktrace:

```
04-15 09:28:25.064: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16943): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-15 09:28:25.064: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16943): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{be.test.helloworld/be.test.helloworld.activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-15 09:28:25.064: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16943):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2781)
04-15 09:28:25.064: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16943):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2797)
04-15 09:28:25.064: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16943):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-15 09:28:25.064: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16943):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2132)
04-15 09:28:25.064: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16943):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-15 09:28:25.064: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16943):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
04-15 09:28:25.064: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16943):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4914)
04-15 09:28:25.064: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16943):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-15 09:28:25.064: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16943):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-15 09:28:25.064: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16943):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
04-15 09:28:25.064: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16943):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
04-15 09:28:25.064: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16943):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-15 09:28:25.064: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16943): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-15 09:28:25.064: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16943):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:146)
04-15 09:28:25.064: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16943):     at be.test.helloworld.data.DataClass.<init>(DataClass.java:23)
04-15 09:28:25.064: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16943):     at be.test.helloworld.data.DataClass.getInstance(DataClass.java:14)
04-15 09:28:25.064: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16943):     at be.test.helloworld.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
04-15 09:28:25.064: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16943):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1065)
04-15 09:28:25.064: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16943):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2745)
04-15 09:28:25.064: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16943):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Call this in `onCreate()` of your `Application` subclass

Comment: I've changed the code to:
 public void onCreate() {
  super.onCreate();
  settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
  Log.e("temp", "DataClass constructor executed");
  
 }
    
    
 /*public DataClass() {
  settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); //nullpointer here
  Log.e("temp", "DataClass constructor executed");
 }*/

But getSharedPreferences method and the log aren't executed

Comment: Put `@Override` over your `onCreate()` signature to see if Eclipse cribs. Debug to see if it is being called.

Comment: When I use a regular constructor as I show in my beginpost it get's called but gives nullpointer when getting shared preferences. When I use the oncreate with override notation it doesn't get called..

Comment: Remove it from your constructor and see if `onCreate()` gets a chance to get called.

Comment: Can you show your updated code? (pls do it in your question, as it doesn't format well in comments)

Comment: I'm trying a new approach extending android.app.application. Thanks for the effort

Comment: I thought that's what you were doing so far

Comment: Yes but I didn't knew it had singleton build in. My getInstance method is unnecessary I now realise. So now I'm trying to instantiate using getApplicationContext instead of getInstance. I'll come back to this as soon as I have my Singleton working which isn't the case (check my latest question).

Answer (score 0):

does this class extend `Activity` class!?

And could you try using `MODE_PRIVATE` instead of `0` on line 3!?

Comment: Quote from question: 'class that Extends Application'

Comment: I don't understand why you would extend `Application` class instead of `Activity` class. That's why I asked this question. Since in my experience, `SharedPreferences` doesn't work when used outside of an `Activity`

Comment: @dmmh maybe, can you please explain?

Comment: well, you can get your SharedPreferences from pretty much anywhere in your application. I'm doing it in a `Service`, for example. To my experience, sofar, there are no limitations to getting it, no matter from where.

Comment: @dmmh That's helpful. Thanks so much!